# how to read file from folder in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me how to read file from folder in jQuery ?Actually I have one folder name "Test" on desktop and inside that I have one file "VoipMosMO#" file.I need to read content of that file.
I am able to read content when I make url(external url) of that file in fiddle.And content is display now I want to get content of that when It is on my pc "Desktop" location inside the folder. ?
fiddle

```
jQuery.get("abc", function(data) {
   alert(data);
   //process text file line by line
   $('#div').html(data.replace('n','<br />'));
});
```

Comment: You can't make Ajax requests to external locations if the server doesn't allow it. I'm relatively certain that Dropbox does not allow it. If you want to access Dropbox files via JS, you should probably use their SDK. Or maybe something like https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore.

Comment: I need to read file from my desktop not from server

Comment: Ah, then the answer is even simpler: You can't. (and actually I'm surprised that Dropbox lets you make that Ajax request, but it's true, when you make an Ajax request, it sets `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*"`)

Comment: Mean I cann't read file text from my internal project directory ?

Comment: Not if the code runs in the browser. That would be huge security risk. You can have a UI that lets you select the file and then read its content, but you can't read the file automatically.

Comment: ok...!!!  But I saw in mobile Project which run on device .I can read file text file from internal memenory

Comment: Haha, then you can use javascript and you will read Peoples files with sensitive data,Do u think javascript/jquery will alone allow you to do so ? NO

Comment: I don't want read automatically.I wiill give the path of my file directory  "you can't read the file automatically."

Comment: Mean there is no way to to read file  if I give hard coded path my code

Comment: Maybe you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications (Google helped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FileReader` api but it supports from `IE10+`

Other than that, ajax requests have no access to the platform details.

May be you can upload your file to the server and access the url from that server.

Else force the user to enter the path of the file and pass that file path to the server and read the file and show it in the client.

Comment: can you please some code how I can read file from my computer

Comment: @user2535959: https://www.google.com/search?q=FileReader+javascript

Comment: @user2535959 [MDN FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)   MDN - Mozilla Developer Network

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access client file or folder using java script. You need something like applet, flash or active x application to do it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: ah yes, we can use HTML5 to do that also